# How do I navigate lighting a Web spell with an oil flask?

Tags: dnd-5e

Character A is standing on a Web spell, and character B lights a flask of oil and throws it at her feet. Does this count as "entering" the fire, thus causing her damage this turn? Or do I wait until she "starts her turn" in the fire zone to take damage? Does she take damage once when it's created and once when she starts her turn?

Edit to add: I think what's confusing my group is that she ought to take 5 damage from the oil lantern, and also, 2d4 from the web being on fire. Does the one supersede the other?

Comment: Oh. I came to this question hoping it was about using flaming webs as impromptu lighthouses on foggy nights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### For the oil when and how much damage the character takes depends on how we model it

A flask of oil can be used as an improvised weapon to cover a character in oil (PHB 152). If the oil is **later** lit it deals 5 damage to the character covered. Alternatively oil can be used to cover an area and then, if later lit, deals damage to any creature that **enters the area or ends its turn their**. There is no provision for handling a lit vial of oil being thrown.

One way of modeling a thrown flask of flaming oil would be to think of it like alchemist's fire. Alchemist's fire can be thrown as an improvised weapon at a creature, and if it hits that creature takes 1d4 damage **at the start of their turn** each round until they put it out. If modeling a pre-burning flask of this way oil I'd have it only burn for one round, and likely have the throw be at disadvantage. I'd still allow it only sparingly considering that alchemist's fire is 50gp whereas a flask of oil is 1/500th the price at 1sp.

### For the burning web Character A takes damage at the start of her turn

Generally these effects are worded similar to Spirit Guardians, "...when the creature enters the area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there...". The idea is that a creature will only be effected once each round either

1. When they start their turn, because they are inside the effect
2. When they enter the effect, because now they are inside the effect

So in your example Character A will take damage at the start of their turn because they start their turn standing in a fire.

Comment: I updated the first post, because I think there's two sources of damage here and this answer only addresses one

Comment: @Yamikuronue I've added some information on throwing a flask of oil to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

**For the flask of oil**: she takes damage on the turn the oil is thrown at her. This then ignites the ...

**Web**: at the start of her turn. This is specifically spelt out in the last paragraph of the spell's description.